# How to calculate the time difference in angular for Unix epoch time?

Tags: angular, unix-timestamp

*Currently I am receiving a created task field in Unix epoch format in tasks component. And I would like to calculate how much time its been the task has created.*

For example : if the task created 2 Hours/Days/Minutes ago : I want to display it like **"Created 2 hours/Days/Minutes ago"**.

what would be the easiest way to do this in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript library called moment.js. It can handle and formatting times.

It's as easy as
`moment.unix(yourUnixEpochTime).fromNow()`

https://momentjs.com

Comment: The library looks good but is there any other way without a third party library. The libraries within angular?